# How to test object that contains array using jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to test object that contains several complicated fields:

1. one of the fields contains array of objects.
2. one of the fields contains object that one of its fields contains array of objects.

I tried to use `expect(createdRequest).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(originRequestData));`.
I also tried to use `expect().toMatchObject()` and another a lot of methods but none of them worked.

**This is interface of the object I want to test**:

```
export interface IRequest {
  id?: string;
  openDate?: Date;
  closeDate: Date;
  approvals:
  {
    replyUser: Types.ObjectId;
    answer: number | null;
  }[]; // Array of objects
  target: {
    recordId?: Types.ObjectId;
    collectionName: string;
  };
  action: {
    actionType: ActionType;
    additionalData: AdditonalDataType[]; // Array of objects. note: AdditonalDataType  
                                         // is an interface of object.
  };
  comment?: string;
  requester: Types.ObjectId;
}
```

**The mock I use:**

```
export const validRequest: IRequest = {
  closeDate: new Date('12/10/2030'),
  approvals: [{
    replyUser: new Types.ObjectId(),
    answer: 2,
  }],
  target: {
    recordId: Types.ObjectId(),
    collectionName: 'occupations',
  },
  action: {
    actionType: ActionType.create,
    additionalData: [{
      field: 'job',
      value: 'chef',
    }],
  },
  requester: new Types.ObjectId(),
};
```

**The test I wrote**:

```
test('Should create a single request', async () => {
  const createdRequest: IRequest = await RequestsManager.create(validRequest);
  expect(createdRequest).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(validRequest));
});
```

**The error I received**:
[image]

Comment: have you tried https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#custom-matchers-api?

Comment: You could try comparing the `JSON.stringify()` result of both of them.

Comment: It can be solved with custom matcher of jest but I wish to find more simple solution. It's sounds like a basic requirement so it's weird to me that custom matcher is the only solution. @Itamar

Comment: I can't because the objects are not the same - 'createdRequest' contains more fields then 'validRequest'. My test should check that createdRequest contains validRequest @Taplar

Comment: A solution without custom matcher is to write expected object specifically for an assertion, `approvals: [expect.objectContaining({ replyUser: new Types.ObjectId(), answer: 2, })]` and so on.